# Get the average from xml list

Tags: java, xml, date, loops

I have a list (USAGE_LIST) of data that contains some fields year and month and usage, i would like to get the average of the last 3 months of the usage field, 
I tried something like Calendar.getInstance() with SimpleDateFormat and getTime()
but becuase i dont have really date, it doest work, what is the best way to do that, please an example. thanks and thanks for StackoverFlow

```
<USAGE_LIST>
            <TOTAL>
            <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
            <MONTH>10</MONTH>
            <USAGE>200</USAGE>
            </TOTAL>
            <TOTAL>
            <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
            <MONTH>11</MONTH>
            <USAGE>250</USAGE>
            </TOTAL>
            <TOTAL>
            <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
            <MONTH>12</MONTH>
            <USAGE>500</USAGE>
            </TOTAL>
            <TOTAL>
            <YEAR>2014</YEAR>
            <MONTH>1</MONTH>
            <USAGE>300</USAGE>
            </TOTAL>
</USAGE_LIST>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote fully working example for you. It contains XML reading, filtering old dates and average usage counting. I used xpath to retrieve elements from your XML file.

Please note that usage list you provided contains only dates MORE than 3 months old. So to make it work (and output something else than 0) you need to add / modify it to have more recent dates.

Just copy and pase this example and add usage list xml file to same source folder.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class AverageUsage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        int usageSum = 0;
        int usageCount = 0;

        // Create calendar representing now (used later)
        Calendar threeMonthsBefore = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Subtract 3 months from now
        threeMonthsBefore.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse("src/data.xml");

            // Create XPathFactory object
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            // Create xpath expression to query our totals
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/USAGE_LIST/TOTAL");

            // Evaluate expression result on XML document
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            // Iterate over all TOTAL elements
            for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
                // Current total element
                Element total = (Element)nodes.item(i);

                // Get YEAR, MONTH, USAGE elements from current TOTAL element
                Element year = (Element)total.getElementsByTagName("YEAR").item(0);
                Element month = (Element)total.getElementsByTagName("MONTH").item(0);
                Element usage = (Element)total.getElementsByTagName("USAGE").item(0);

                // Read values as int
                int yearValue = Integer.valueOf(year.getTextContent());
                int monthValue = Integer.valueOf(month.getTextContent());
                int usageValue = Integer.valueOf(usage.getTextContent());

                // Get calendar instance & reset it
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
                cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
                cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
                cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                cal.clear(Calendar.DATE);

                // Set calendar date
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearValue);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthValue);

                // Check if cal date is less than 3 months old
                if(cal.after(threeMonthsBefore)){
                    usageSum += usageValue;
                    usageCount++;
                }
            }

            if(usageCount > 0){
                float average = usageSum / (float) usageCount;
                System.out.println("Average usage in past 3 months is: " + average);

            }else{
                System.out.println("There were no usage in past 3 months.");
            }


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException
                | XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A rather good illustration, it seems to me, of why XML processing is much better done in XPath/XQuery than in low-level Java code...

Comment: After some code change of my side, your example works fine for my problem. thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. And this style of XML node querying is much more portable and readable, especially for very complicated sructures

Answer (score 0):

You still can construct a `Calendar` instance with the *year* and *month* only, try something as the following:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get a new calendar instance
calendar.clear(); // Clear it
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // Set the new month and year
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
Date date = calendar.getTime(); //Get you date value
```

Comment: I tried that but beause what I get is not a real date but a String it doesnt work

Comment: Please add your marshalling code along with how are you reading the xml elements, I cannot figure out the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Calendar instance, `Calendar.getInstance()` ,and `Calendar.set` it to the date needed. You can set it using `Calendar.Year` and `Calendar.Month` as parameters.

Lets assume you have read the xml file into a `String[]` where each line is a element in the array. Simply iterate over the array, checking year and month, and when they are the correct set, iterate once more and parse out the usage. Repeat to 3 times and calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the last three months", but let's assume you mean "the average USAGE for all TOTAL elements whose YEAR/MONTH is within three months before today's date".

Depending exactly how you want the date arithmetic to work, in XPath 2.0 or XQuery 3.0 that can be expressed something like

```
avg(/USAGE_LIST/TOTAL[(current-date() - xs:date(concat(YEAR, '-', MONTH, '-01')
                        gt xs:dayTimeDuration('P90D')])
```

There are of course a number of XPath 2.0 and/or XQuery 1.0 libraries you can call from Java; Saxon is one.

The exact meaning of the expression above is to get the average of all months where the 1st of the month occurred in the last 90 days. If you want to state more precisely what your intent is, I'm sure XPath 2.0 is powerful enough to reflect it.